# Error 110434 using the MaxEnt tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, error, maxent, nlcd

First time using the Presence-only prediction tool (MaxEnt) and I've been running scenarios with it and testing how different parameters look as outputs. When I try to run the tool using the NLCD land use raster as the categorical variable it gives me the error code "Error 110434: This analysis could not be completed because the following variables did not have at least two data points in a category.". I'm not sure how to fix this so that I can use it for my scenarios.